# Angular : How to Add/Remove Files in the Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here i choose multiple images and shows using `*ngFor` And there I have placed a delete button which is appear in the screenshot, click on delete button i want to delete chosen image from chosen list i tried below code but i not getting proper solution.

[image: This is My UI sceenshot]

add.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>

<input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput multiple="true">

<div *ngFor="let selected of selectedFile;let index = index">
  <h3>{{selected.name}}</h3>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)">delete</button>
</div>
```

add.component.ts

```
selectedFile: File;
ArrayOfSelectedFile = new Array<string>();

onFileChanged(event : any) {
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile= [];
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files;
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.push(event.target.files);
}

removeSelectedFile(index){
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: if you add `console.log(this.ArrayOfSelectedFile)` after the `splice` method, does the element got removed ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>

<input style="display: none"  #attachments type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput multiple="true">

<div *ngFor="let selected of listOfFiles;let index = index">
  <h3>{{selected}}</h3>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)">delete</button>
</div>
```

And TS code:

Import this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

And Inside your component class:

```
@ViewChild('attachments') attachment: any;

fileList: File[] = [];
listOfFiles: any[] = [];

onFileChanged(event: any) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= event.target.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var selectedFile = event.target.files[i];
      this.fileList.push(selectedFile);
      this.listOfFiles.push(selectedFile.name)
  }

  this.attachment.nativeElement.value = '';
}



removeSelectedFile(index) {
 // Delete the item from fileNames list
 this.listOfFiles.splice(index, 1);
 // delete file from FileList
 this.fileList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

If you notice that the Deleted file is not available for upload again for that I have used `@ViewChild` to reset the `value = ''`, then you can select the deleted file again.

Here is a working [`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8cx2r) example.

Comment: Instead of using multiple, can we add a button to add a new file with description? Like it should be iterate n number of times when you click on a button. Can we get this scenario done using reactive forms with validation?

Comment: @SaiManoj need more clear idea, can you post a question with details, demo?

Comment: let me do that and will tag it here. Will make a sample stackblitz too for a brief

Comment: @SaiManoj sure also you can mail me the question link..my mail id given in my Prof info

Comment: Great. Will be doing that too. Thanks mate.

Comment: Here is the link for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62717220/9380480)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove it from a `selectedFile` array.

```
this.selectedFile.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: @VictoryRodniansky selectedFile type is File so it shows error like this [ts] Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'File'

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but could you write in html:
<div *ngFor="let selected of ArrayOfSelectedFile;let index = index">

Comment: @DDD in your case selectedFile is not of type File, but FileList.

Answer (score 0):

event.target.files is already an array, which is why you can iterate over it with ngFor.
When you assign selectedFile = event.target.files, you are making it an array.
Try this:

```
selectedFile: File;
ArrayOfSelectedFile = new Array<string>();

onFileChanged(event : any) {
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile = event.target.files;
}

removeSelectedFile(index){
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.splice(index,1);
}

<div *ngFor="let selected of ArrayOfSelectedFile;let index = index">
  <h3>{{selected.name}}</h3>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)">delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i got error this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.splice is not a function

Comment: this.ArrayOfSelectedFile = event.target.files as string[];

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Multiple file upload delete](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nafjup), let me know if you want any clarification on same.

Comment: Try to upload deleted file again and then check!

Comment: @DDD Have you test this--> *Try to upload deleted file again*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale its working like new upload, if you want append then you need to remove `this.fileList = []` from `fileUpload()` and loop `event.target.files` and push it into `this.fileList`

Comment: @DDD its working from your side? or need any modification

Comment: @R.Viral its working like new upload i want to append new images so can you modify answer for that

Comment: @DDD can you please check, i did. on same link

Comment: The link doesn't work.  This is why its much more advantageous to add detail to an answer rather than just supplying a link

Answer (score 0):

In your html code

```
 <label class="form-label">Add Images</label>
      <input type="file"
             class="form-control"
             (change)="onSelectFile($event)"
             multiple accept="image/*" />
    </div>
```

//this is your ts code

```
onSelectFile(event) {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageurls.push({ base64String: event.target.result, });
     }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
    }
  }
 }
```

For more details:https://findandsolve.com/articles/how-to-upload-and-remove-multiple-image-using-anular-code-example

Answer (score 0):

There are two better ways to achieve this if you want to avoid explicit for loop.

1- Using spread operator:

```
    ArrayOfSelectedFile: File[] =[];

    onFileChanged(event : any) {
      this.ArrayOfSelectedFile = [...event.target.files];
    }

    removeSelectedFile(index){
      this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.splice(index,1);
    }
```

`event.target.files` is `FileList` object. To remove a file from a JavaScript FileList is to use the spread operator to convert the FileList to an array.
And in `removeSelectedFile` function, you can use `splice` function to remove an element of particular index.

2- Using Array.from method:

```
ArrayOfSelectedFile: File[] =[];

onFileChanged(event : any) {
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile = Array.from(event.target.files);
}

removeSelectedFile(index){
  this.ArrayOfSelectedFile.splice(index,1);
}
```