# How to erase form data after upload

Tags: angular, file-upload

I have an upload method that works great, but I am trying to modify it so that after the upload is done the form data is erased. Specifically I'm trying to get rid of the name of the file after upload (wrong.png), but I want to make sure that if I click upload again there is no trace of the last file left.

I tried using formData.reset(), and setting the file=null in angular but neither one worked.

[image]

HTML

```
<h1>Upload new file (.png or .jpg)</h1>
<input #file type="file" multiple (change)="upload(file.files)" />
```

ANGULAR

```
upload(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
        return;

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let file of files) {
        formData.append(file.name, file);
    }
    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `/api/FileUpload`, formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate when you say when you click again there is no trace of last file left, what do you mean by this? Where should the last file be not visible?

Comment: You want the test "wrong.png" to disappear after your post is done?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537297/7124761) will help, its working fine for every single scenario

Comment: A feedback over added answers, asked comments is always nice and cheerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the chosen file to disappear after your POST request is done, then set the value of the file type input as `null`. You can pipe your observable and use `tap()` to achieve this.

```
@ViewChild('file') file;
upload(files) {
  if (files.length === 0)
      return;

  const formData = new FormData();

  for (let file of files) {
      formData.append(file.name, file);
  }
  const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `/api/FileUpload`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
  }).pipe(tap(_ => {
    this.file.nativeElement.value = null
  });
}
```