# Iterate file upload with description using FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a form which will have n fields including file upload. I'm trying to iterate file upload on click of a button. So by default there will be one file. So when user clicks on add button, one more set of file upload should be added.So my output should be something like array of n file objects.

Expected output for file upload:

```
[
 {
  file: image1,
  fileDescription: file1
 },
 {
  file: image2,
  fileDescription: my second image
 }
]
```

Deleted file is not available for upload again for that I have used `@ViewChild` to reset the `value = ''`, then you can select the deleted file again. This was added from one of the answers by [Prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7124761/prashant-pimpale)

Note: All the above should have validation. Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z29ahg) so far I have tried.

Comment: Allow some time, will check ASAP and try to resolve

Comment: Sorry, was busy yesterday, but seems you got the answer!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale No problem. I understand. Facing issue while editing the form in same page. Trying to fix that. Actually I'm sending file in base 64 with key `fileContent`, but I'm getting file in `filePath` with hash key. So now i need to hit one more `url` with this `filePath` to download the file. But how can I display the files in edit mode? So users can either add new file or modify existing file or can delete the file. One file upload should be mandatory in edit mode too. I will try and post a new question if i didn't get find the way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a **FormArray**, and push a new value each time the user click on the "add file upload button".

You can find a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg1szu

Comment: Thanks mate. Can we make this as separate file as `<file-upload></file-upload>`

Comment: Yes, you can! In https://medium.com/@joaqcid/angular-custom-form-controls-series-3d56884bdb99 you can find more information about creating reusable Form Components.

Comment: There's one issue. Here i'm not able to see error message for file description if it's not valid. If you fix that would be helpful

Comment: Please take a look again

Comment: Now it's not showing for file button. Validation should be for both.

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect for my use case. If you get time can you help me with this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725821/patch-values-to-checkbox-using-patchvalue-in-angular)